# Java 8 - Using ConcurrentHashMap.merge in a class and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

While trying out the merge in ConcurrentHashMap, I designed the following class to do the following:

1. Add a `value` (double) for a key. If there is an existing `Statistic` for that key then recalculate the running total (which is the sum of all the values so far seen), the `counter` is incremented (to take into account the number of hits).
2. To clarify, let's take an example: we need to hold the `response times` for a particular method invocation. For each `response time`, we invoke the "`addStatistic`" method and pass in a "`response time"`. The `response time` is accumulated, the `counter` is incremented (to account for one more invocation event) and the `min` and `max` are recalculated and added as a `Statistic` back for that key.

This is a draft implementation of the functionality that captures, for example, the "response time" of an invocation.

Now the ConcurrentHashMap.[merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), is documented as atomic and am taking care to not leak any references, was wondering if there is a thread safety / race condition in this code?

```
public class SummaryStatistics implements SummaryStatisticsI {


public static class Statistic {
    private double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    private double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    // the sum of all the values seen so far
    private DoubleAccumulator runningValue = new DoubleAccumulator((x, y) -> x + y, 0.0);
    private int counter = 0;

    protected double getMin() {
        return min;
    }
    protected double getMax() {
        return max;
    }
    protected double getValue() {
        return runningValue.get();
    }
    protected int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

}

private final Map<String, Statistic> statsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private Map<String, Statistic> getStatsMap() {
        return statsMap;

}

@Override
public void addStatistic(String key, double value) {
    Statistic s2 = new Statistic();
    s2.runningValue.accumulate(value);
    s2.min = value;
    s2.max = value;
    s2.counter++;

    getStatsMap().merge(key, s2, new BiFunction<Statistic, Statistic, Statistic>() {

        @Override
        public Statistic apply(Statistic oldValue, Statistic s2) {
            // only called when there is an existing value for this key
            // all of this is atomic
            oldValue.max = oldValue.max > s2.max ? oldValue.max : s2.max;
            oldValue.min = oldValue.min < s2.min ? oldValue.min : s2.min;
            // s2.min == s2.max == s2.runningValue.get()
            oldValue.runningValue.accumulate(s2.min);
            oldValue.counter++;

            return oldValue;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Statistic getStatistic(String key) {
    return getStatsMap().get(key);
}
```

}

Comment: Curious, is this just practice to better know concurrency or are you considering implementing it into production code? If it's the latter I'd highly recommend http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/.

Comment: This is rather a review question, which is more suited for the [code  review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site.